# Using a window.load function in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, crossrider

I want to run some code after everything on the target page is done loading AND rendering. It was suggested to me to use the Window.load function and it is working perfectly in Firefox and Chrome. I just can't get it to work in IE. Is there another way of doing this?

Edit: Ok so here is what I have:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
if (appAPI.isMatchPages("192.168.1.156/test/*")) 
{
    $("body").css("display","none");

    if ( $('.welcome p').text().indexOf("user") >= 0 )
    {
        if ( $('h1').text().indexOf("header") >= 0 )
        {
            //alert("Found data");
            $('td:contains("testdata")').text("newdata");
        }
    }

    $(window).load(function () {
        $("body").css("display","block");
    });
}
});
```

Basically before there was code flickering, I could see the data being changed as the page loaded so I asked for some advice and the solution I got was to set the body style to `display:none` and use window.load to set it back to block once everything is loaded. This works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE. The actual code that changes the data works in IE tho.

Comment: Show us what you tried. Some code please

Comment: It should work. `Window.load` Function works fine in IE.

Comment: which jquery version with which IE version? Any error in console?

Comment: I suggest you to show us your code.

Comment: I edited my original post with the code I am trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

You should have no issue with this in IE, I use it frequently when I need to ensure all resources have been downloaded:

```
$( window ).load(function() {
  // Run code
});
```

"Run a function when the page is fully loaded including graphics." ref: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: I have no idea why would you post an answer like that...which is not even an answer :P

Comment: @Ani: Why is it not an answer? It demonstrates exactly how to use the `load` even on `window` with jQuery (the question is tagged `jquery`), and it refers to the documentation. It's rather more of an answer than the question deserves, frankly.

Comment: Because i don't think OP is asking for syntax. He said it works fine in other browser, which makes me thinks syntax is correct.

Comment: @Ani: Meh, okay. With questions as vague and incomplete as this one, I tend to discount claims like that. The number of times I've seen "it works in X" when there was no chance whatsoever that it worked in X...

Comment: Not necessarily, Ani. IE, especially older versions, played loosy-goosy with the spec, and the benefit of leveraging jQuery in the fashion I indicated above is the framework very adeptly manages the vagaries between all the different browsers and versions. If the code I posted above is used, the OP will have no issue, even down to IE7.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  Exactly my point. When the question is incomplete why would you write an answer like that.

Comment: I suppose I could have voted to close the question as well, but it's three days before Xmas, I'm stuck in an airport for the foreseeable future, and I'm in the holiday spirit :)

Comment: No offense to anyone. Happy Holidays !!!..Just trying to help someone who will stumble upon this question for an answer